# flowCover - find out which item is in the centre (being displayed) iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using http://www.chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.m and would like to know how I may display a label for each image when it is displayed in the flowcover (the current image)

Thanks,

:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest reading the documentation before posting questions. With no familiarity with this library at all, in 30 seconds, I downloaded the source, found the docs, and skimmed until I found - (void)flowCover:(FlowCoverView *)view didSelect:(int)cover, which appears to be a delegate method.

At a glance, it looks like you're not meant to know what's front and center, only what the user picked (which may very well mean "what just became front and center"). Test it and see.

Comment: That only triggers the method if the user selects the image. Which is not what I need

Comment: Then you're probably going to have to delve into the source code and extend it to report the front-most item as the documentation does not mention any such notification is provided.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get this notification by changing the Delegate Protocol in FlowCoverView.h like this:

```
@protocol FlowCoverViewDelegate
- (int)flowCoverNumberImages:(FlowCoverView *)view;
- (UIImage *)flowCover:(FlowCoverView *)view cover:(int)cover;
- (void)flowCover:(FlowCoverView *)view didSelect:(int)cover;
- (void)flowCover:(FlowCoverView *)view highlighted:(int)cover; //<-- Added
@end
```

And replacing your `-[FlowCoverView driveAnimation]` method in FlowCoverView.m with this:

```
- (void)driveAnimation
{
    double elapsed = CACurrentMediaTime() - startTime;
    if (elapsed >= runDelta) [self endAnimation];
    else [self updateAnimationAtTime:elapsed];

    /*
     * Change by Uppfinnarn <uppfinnarn@gmail.com>.
     * This will give the Delegate a message every time the highlighted cover (eg. the one in the center) changes.
     * Can be used to display subtitles for example.
     */

    if (delegate) [delegate flowCover:self highlighted:(int)floor(offset + 0.01)];  // make sure .99 is 1
```

}

Create a UILabel somewhere and place it on top of the FlowCoverView (make sure it's opaque is NO so that it doesn't create a black box behind it), then monitor `-[flowCover:highlighted:]` to know which cover is currently in the center and change the text accordingly.

Note that this won't give you a notification for when the view is first created, only once the animation moves. You have to figure out the first title yourself.

<s>Also, this won't give you notifications while the user is dragging with their finger, only when it's "gliding freely".</s>

EDIT:
Replace your `-[FlowCoverView touchesMoved:withEvent:]` method with this to get callbacks when the user is dragging with their fingers too:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGRect r = self.bounds;
    UITouch *t = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint where = [t locationInView:self];
    double pos = (where.x / r.size.width) * 10 - 5;

    if (touchFlag) {
            // determine if the user is dragging or not
            int dx = fabs(where.x - startTouch.x);
            int dy = fabs(where.y - startTouch.y);
            if ((dx < 3) && (dy < 3)) return;
            touchFlag = NO;
    }

    int max = [self numTiles]-1;

    offset = startOff + (startPos - pos);
    if (offset > max) offset = max;
    if (offset < 0) offset = 0;
    /*
     * Change by Uppfinnarn <uppfinnarn@gmail.com>.
     * Based on Ilkka Pirttimaa <ilkka.pirttimaa@gmail.com>'s solution for notifications.
     * when the animation stops.
     * 
     * This will give the Delegate a message every time the highlighted cover (eg. the one in the center) changes.
     * Can be used to display subtitles for example.
     */
    if(delegate) [delegate flowCover:self highlighted:(int)floor(offset + 0.01)];
    [self draw];

    double time = CACurrentMediaTime();
    if (time - startTime > 0.2) {
        startTime = time;
        lastPos = pos;
    }
}
```